# Can I use Android/iOS plugins in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk

I'm building an app which cannot use IAP and instead needs a third party payment gateway. Problem is, I'm unable to find payment gateway plugins for Corona.
However, many companies provide plugins for Android and iOS.
My question is, can I use these plugins in Corona using some wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You would have to create the Corona wrapper yourself (or pay someone to do it for you) if another developer haven't already done so.

You can check for the community plugins at https://marketplace.coronalabs.com